# TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD error using "Fireworks" and "Explosion" particle systems in Unity 5.5

Tags: unity, c#, particles

I receive a `TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD` error whenever I add certain prefab particle system assets, such as "Fireworks" and "Explosion", to my scene.

---

It also generates a huge amount of log messages, such as

> Allocation of 752 bytes at 0524a60f
>   Allocation of 22960 bytes at 0542a6f0
>   ...

It also creates a huge amount of lag and, severely drops the frame rate.

---

Particle systems like "Flare", "Dust Storm" and "AfterBurner" work as expected. The individual simulation of the child particle systems in the "Explosion" and "Fire" prefabs worked perfectly in the scene view, but the same prefabs simulate weirdly in the game.

---

I am using Unity 5.5, and this error should have been fixed in 5.4.0 b23, but apparently it has not. How do I fix these issues?

Comment: What makes you think this was a specific error that was fixed in 5.4.0 b23? Also, it is impossible to tell what you mean by "doesn't look right" or "simulate weirdly". Perhaps you should record a .gig of your scene view while you simulate these behaviours, to post for better clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on a fix for this issue. You can track it here: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/tls-allocator-alloc-temp-thread-error-caused-by-particle-systems

Having the same sub emitter used at 2 or more different levels of the hierarchy causes it.

Comment: This err appears in 17.3.0f3. Please change status in tracker: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/tls-allocator-alloc-temp-thread-error-caused-by-particle-systems

Updated to 17.3.0p4 and errors are gone